# Cross-platform portable app suite / creator

Tags: cross-platform, portable

Having a collection of portable applications at hand, has proven to be very helpful several times.

I wonderer whether any **portable app suite** or **portable app creator** provides a **cross-plattform approach** that supports managing

- cross-plattform and
- multi-plattform tools,

ideally

- sharing their configuration files and
- keeping them up to date.

Comment: (1) Does the solution itself need to be portable? -- (2) On which platform(s) does the solution need to run? -- (3) What is the difference between "cross-platform" and "multi-platform"?

Comment: @unor re 3) I would read cross-platform as running under multiple OSs _possibly on the same hardware_ Vs multi-platform one user using the same software on more than one set of hardware, _probably running the same OS,_ but retaining preferences, licence, etc.

Answer (score -1):

For cross platform you could look to satisfy your requirements with [python](http://python.org), (available for just about every platform, pre-installed on most other than windows and for windows there is [PortablePython](http://portablepython.com) if you cannot install python).

Of course a lot depends upon the range of applications that you need to have available.

***Disclaimer:*** *I seem to be recommending python/portable python a lot - this is because I use and **like** them and find that they provide a very powerful and flexible set of tools **not** because of any vested interests.*